# ResourceResolverFactory Service Reference failing from Scheduler Jobs

Tags: aem

We are writing few scheduler jobs. As a simple pattern, I wrote one scheduler class that governs all cron scheduling and worker jobs are written in separate classes.

The job class looks simple like:

```
@Component
@Service
public class DeamonJob implements Runnable {
    @Reference 
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;
}

public void run() {
  // business logic.
}
```

Now this resolver factory is always null. Since this job is instantiated from scheduler as

```
DeamonJob j = new DeamonJob();
scheduler.schedule(j, schedulerOptions);
```

Since we are not invoking service from sling (like sling.getService()), I believe the service context will be missing in Job class and respective service references are failing.

Is this wrong pattern? Examples for scheduler always clubs the job and scheduler in same class. Is there a way I can separate into scheduler and job classes and invoke service references from job threads?

Comment: is this issue specific to ResourceResolverFactory? are you able to get instance of any other service using @Reference?

Comment: No. Not able get handle of any services called using @Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use @Reference, you must use the "singleton" Sling Service and not instantiate it manually. You can either define the quartz scheduler directly:

```
@Component
@Service
@Properties({ @Property(label = "Cron Expression", name = "scheduler.expression", value = "0 0 0 * * ?") })
public class DeamonJob implements Runnable
```

Or you create your Runnable as a simple class without the Annotations and provide the ResourceResolver in the constructor:

```
public class DeamonJob implements Runnable {

    private final ResourceResolver resolver;

    public DeamonJob(ResourceResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public void run() {
        // business logic.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Worker job classes are not candidate for osgi services, since services needs to be singleton and jobs might be executed concurrently in threads. I ll change my implementation accordingly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I am still confused why did this statement `@Reference 
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;` not work?

Comment: @awadheshv Because he instantiated `DeamonJob` with `new DeamonJob()`. These injections only work in OSGi beans. `@Service` defines an OSGi service which instantiates a singleton instance of `DeamonJob` when the bundle starts and there the injection is done for any `@Reference`, if there is a matching instance in the OSGi. container. When using `new` within your normal code, no injection can take place.

Answer (score 0):

I got an alternate to invoke services from POJO classes.

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ResourceResolverFactory.class).getBundleContext();
ResourceResolverFactory factory = (ResourceResolverFactory) bundleContext.getService(bundleContext.getServiceReference(ResourceResolverFactory.class.getName()));
```

This works for me though not sure if this is good practice.